# Login loop with Nvidia proprietary driver and after uninstall lost both wired and wireless network

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, network-manager, dkms

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run proprietary drivers installed along with DKMS long time ago. Due to a recent ubuntu update, First there was a login loop issue , then after uninstalling the proprietary drivers, it started using open source X.org X server as default. But I seem to loose both wired and wireless internet due to "no network devices " available.

I looked at some of the questions but could not solve it myself. Can anyone link which questions or workaround should help me out of this ?

Comment: Geforce GTX 750ti  graphics card.

Comment: choosing a different linux kernel in grub and running in recovery mode helped me to get back my network drivers back for some strange reason.  for info, I have Atheros  and Intel 3165 wireless card.  Ubuntu 16.04.2 has latest 375.39 nvidia deb available in software. so instead of separately installing proprietary drivers with DKMS, install the  drivers from "additional drivers " dialogbox. once internet is back I have updating the linux kernel headers to latest version.

Comment: Hi Downvoter: Can you suggest why you have downvoted ? Can you enlist what  needs to be improved in the Q  , i shall happily do it ?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on my DELL Precision 5510. After removing all NVIDIA stuff, I lost all network connections. Could you please post your solution as a real answer including the detail on how you actually got your network drivers back and what it is exactly about regarding this "additional drivers" dialogbox e.t.c.? Much appreciated. I hardly ever see the GRUB menu on bootup. So how to intentionally get there to switch to an older kernel on start up?